# I have json logs for node error and I have to print one by one

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, angular

I have a error message like this in json

```
{
    "message": "2023-08-04T13:52:01: Error: listen EADDRINUSE: address already in use :::55002023-08-04T13:52:01:     at Server.setupListenHandle [as _listen2] (node:net:1432:16)2023-08-04T13:52:01:     at listenInCluster (node:net:1480:12)2023-08-04T13:52:01:     at Server.listen (node:net:1568:7)2023-08-04T13:52:01:     at ExpressAdapter.listen (/var/www/html/01-haiku/haiku_back/node_modules/@nestjs/platform-express/adapters/express-adapter.js:68:32)2023-08-04T13:52:01:     at /var/www/html/01-haiku/haiku_back/node_modules/@nestjs/core/nest-application.js:166:302023-08-04T13:52:01:     at new Promise (<anonymous>)2023-08-04T13:52:01:     at NestApplication.listen (/var/www/html/01-haiku/haiku_back/node_modules/@nestjs/core/nest-application.js:155:16)2023-08-04T13:52:01:     at bootstrap (/var/www/html/01-haiku/haiku_back/src/main.ts:36:9) {2023-08-04T13:52:01:   code: 'EADDRINUSE',2023-08-04T13:52:01:   errno: -98,2023-08-04T13:52:01:   syscall: 'listen',2023-08-04T13:52:01:   address: '::',2023-08-04T13:52:01:   port: 55002023-08-04T13:52:01: }",
    "timestamp": "2023-08-04T08:22:01.151Z",
    "type": "err",
    "process_id": 0,
    "app_name": "local-haiku-api"
}
```

But I want to display(print) below like that in a html page

```
"2023-08-04T13:52:01: Error: listen EADDRINUSE: address already in use :::55002023-08-04T13:52:01:    
   at Server.setupListenHandle [as _listen2] (node:net:1432:16 undefined)2023-08-04T13:52:01:    
   at listenInCluster .listenInCluster (node:net:1480:12 undefined)2023-08-04T13:52:01:    
   at Server.listen (node:net:1568:7 undefined)2023-08-04T13:52:01:    
   at ExpressAdapter.listen (/var/www/html/01-haiku/haiku_back/node_modules/@nestjs/platform-express/adapters/express-adapter.js:68:32 undefined)2023-08-04T13:52:01:     at /var/www/html/01-haiku/haiku_back/node_modules/@nestjs/core/nest-application.js:166:302023-08-04T13:52:01:    
   at new Promise .new Promise (<anonymous> undefined)2023-08-04T13:52:01:    
   at NestApplication.listen (/var/www/html/01-haiku/haiku_back/node_modules/@nestjs/core/nest-application.js:155:16 undefined)2023-08-04T13:52:01:    
   at bootstrap .bootstrap (/var/www/html/01-haiku/haiku_back/src/main.ts:36:9 undefined) {2023-08-04T13:52:01:   code: 'EADDRINUSE',2023-08-04T13:52:01:   errno: -98,2023-08-04T13:52:01:   syscall: 'listen',2023-08-04T13:52:01:   address: '::',2023-08-04T13:52:01:   port: 55002023-08-04T13:52:01: }"
```

How to achieve this?

Answer (score -1):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Error Message</title>
</head>
<body>
  <pre id="error-message"></pre>

  <script>
    const errorMessage = {
      "message": "2023-08-04T13:52:01: Error: listen EADDRINUSE: address already in use :::55002023-08-04T13:52:01:     at Server.setupListenHandle [as _listen2] (node:net:1432:16)2023-08-04T13:52:01:     at listenInCluster (node:net:1480:12)2023-08-04T13:52:01:     at Server.listen (node:net:1568:7)2023-08-04T13:52:01:     at ExpressAdapter.listen (/var/www/html/01-haiku/haiku_back/node_modules/@nestjs/platform-express/adapters/express-adapter.js:68:32)2023-08-04T13:52:01:     at /var/www/html/01-haiku/haiku_back/node_modules/@nestjs/core/nest-application.js:166:302023-08-04T13:52:01:     at new Promise (<anonymous>)2023-08-04T13:52:01:     at NestApplication.listen (/var/www/html/01-haiku/haiku_back/node_modules/@nestjs/core/nest-application.js:155:16)2023-08-04T13:52:01:     at bootstrap (/var/www/html/01-haiku/haiku_back/src/main.ts:36:9) {2023-08-04T13:52:01:   code: 'EADDRINUSE',2023-08-04T13:52:01:   errno: -98,2023-08-04T13:52:01:   syscall: 'listen',2023-08-04T13:52:01:   address: '::',2023-08-04T13:52:01:   port: 55002023-08-04T13:52:01: }",
      "timestamp": "2023-08-04T08:22:01.151Z",
      "type": "err",
      "process_id": 0,
      "app_name": "local-haiku-api"
    };

    const errorMessageText = errorMessage.message
      .replace(/(\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}T\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}:)/g, '\n$1')
      .replace(/(\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}T\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2})/g, '$1: ')
      .replace(/\t/g, '    ');

    const errorMessageElement = document.getElementById('error-message');
    errorMessageElement.textContent = errorMessageText;
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```